# How to create a fixed size generic buffer in java?

Tags: java, generics

If I want to create a fixed size buffer of ints, I would use `new int[size]`. Now, suppose I want to create a buffer over a generic type.

One possibly solution is:

```
List<T> buffer = new ArrayList<T>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  buffer.add(null);

// now simply access the buffer via buffer.get() and buffer.set()
```

Is there something better I should use? A sample use-case would be to [implement a queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/646/please-review-this-java-synchronous-queue-implementation). Note, this is not a real life usecase, but rather an interview question.

Comment: Umm, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Falmarri - I'm trying to implement a cyclic queue, and would like to use to "buffer like" structure as the underlying data store. I need to be able to allocate a fixed size buffer, and access elements by index.

Comment: But why do you need a buffer that can hold arbitrary objects that you don't know at compile time?

Comment: @Falmarri - because of Java's lack of reified generics.

Comment: Can you add one usecase to your question?

Comment: If you want a Queue, why don't you use a Queue like ArrayBlockingQueue?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
private final T[] items;

public RingBuffer(Class<T> clazz, int capacity) {
    this.items = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, capacity);
}
```

You have to cast to `T[]` but it really is a `T[]` as opposed to `Object[]`

Comment: How is this better than my answer earlier? Reflection is not really necessary here and should be avoided.

Comment: yours is Object[] cast to V[], mine *is* V[] cast to V[]

Comment: The way to guarantee a sort of type-safety in code like this is not making sure the backing store has the right class at creation time, which is moot after type-erasure. You guarantee it in the methods that modify your the backing store - i.e. `add(T t)`, `T pop()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a broken generics system in Java, you cannot use a parametric Array definition, but due to type erasure, you know alternatively you can have an array of Objects assigned to a parametric Array declaration, and then it can get around the VM's type system at run-time.
After this, any operation with this array will have to satisfy type T and the compiler will make sure that happens at compile-time. You just need to get around the definition.

```
class ArrayList<V> {
  private V[] backingArray;
  public ArrayList() {
    backingArray = (V[]) new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE]; 
  }
}
```

[Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html)

Comment: this may work, but Matt's answer is the correct way to initialize such array.

Comment: The only difference is it takes an extra capacity parameter. Both are equally correct and both gives your unchecked warnings. They are just instantiated differently. Mine: `new ArrayList<Integer>()`, @Matts: `new RingBuffer<Integer>(Integer.class, 10)`, the class parameter is totally redundant and and there's unnecessary use of reflection slows down the VM.

Comment: this is okay as long as the array stays inside your class, because inside the class the type V is erased. However, if you ever happen to return the array from a method, or otherwise allow someone from outside of the generic scope to get it, then BOOM it will cause a ClassCastException, because it is not the type you promised them it would be

Comment: Last time I checked `public V[] returnArray() { return backingArray; }` still returns V[]. I can't stop you from casting V[] to anything other than V[] and self-destruct, but how's that different from returning any reference type? Nothing. Once you have instantiated an ArrayList<Integer>(), returnArray returns an Integer[], you still can't assign anything other than an Integer to the array. What's the problem?

Comment: lets say your V was really Integer and I did `Integer[] intArray = yourObjArray.returnArray()` method, it will blow with `ClassCastException`. If implemented with `Array.newInstance` it won't. You can obviously construct an API such that no such use is possible but that doesn't change the fact that your options are limited by use of `new Object[]`.

Comment: It would be surprising if a minor performance overhead (in creating the queue) is an issue in the specified use case (creating a cyclic queue). Such structures tend to hang around for some time and be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a generic collection inside a custom class where you can control the fixed size collection. For example:

```
class Queue<T> {
   private ArrayList<T> q;
   private int size;

   public Queue(int size) {
      this.size = size;
      this.q = new ArrayList<T>(size);
   }

   public int size() {
      return size;
   }

   // ...

   public T get(int index) {
      if (index > q.size()) {
          return null;
      }
      // ... or whatever

      return q.get(index);
   }

}
```

** **EDIT** **

Or more specifically, create your own Collection-compatible generic class. For example :

```
public class FixedQueue<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

   private Object[] queue;

   public FixedQueue(int size) {
      queue = new Object[size];
   }

   @Override
   public E set(int index, E element) {
      Object old = queue[index];
      queue[index] = element;
      modCount++;
      return (E) old;
   }

   @Override
   public E get(int index) {
      return (E) queue[index];
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return queue.length;
   }

   @Override
   public E remove(int index) {
      Object old = queue[index];
      System.arraycopy(queue, index+1, queue, index, queue.length - index - 1);
      modCount++;
      return (E) old;
   }
}
```

This untested class will allow `get` and `set` and `remove` operations, but not `add`, etc. But you may implement it for your own specifications if you want. Implementing a class instead of using a fixed size array will allow you to, if you need to add a functionality (for example `ensureCapacity`) to implement it without touching any other source.

** **UPDATE** **

I just saw your edit, basically, you're starting off right. Just use an array of `Object` that you cast to your generic type when you get an element. See Java's `ArrayList` implementation, for example.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer is different than the code sample I provided in the question.

Comment: in your question, you seem to directly use the `List`, what I'm suggesting is to wrap the `List` in a specific class that will control and restrict it's access to only a fixed number of eleement. Basically, instead of using an array, use a `Collection` (here a `List`) "hide" inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.ArrayDeque` (or java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue) is what you are looking for. Yet, I'd advise you to implement your own cyclic buffer/queue. It's a very good exercise.

As for caching int[] I'd advise you against doing so. 
*Important note*: if you want to use some caching mechanism do not do like tomcat and use ConcurrentLinkedQueue. **Caches SHOULD use stacks** not queues, both ArrayDeque and ArrayBlockingQueue are good for stacks.